# How to create the smart store table in android using salesforce SDK

Tags: java, android, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am using the below source code from salesforce doc but its giving me a 
   below error. How can i resolve it any one can help me.

```
   SmartStoreSDKManager sdkManager = SmartStoreSDKManager.getInstance();
   SmartStore mSmartStore = sdkManager.getSmartStore();


  private void createSoup() {

    IndexSpec[] ACCOUNTS_INDEX_SPEC = {
            new IndexSpec("Name",    SmartStore.Type.string),
            new IndexSpec("Id",      SmartStore.Type.string),
            new IndexSpec("OwnerId", SmartStore.Type.string)
    };
    mSmartStore.registerSoup(ACCOUNTS_SOUP, ACCOUNTS_INDEX_SPEC);
 }
```

When i am calling this method onCreate its showing me a below
    exception.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.runtime, PID: 7033
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>       ComponentInfo{com.runtime/com.runtime.activity.home.HomeActivity}:
>       java.lang.ClassCastException:
>       com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager cannot be cast to
>       com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager  at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
>       at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
>       at
>       android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>       android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)  at
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>       com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)  at
>       dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>       java.lang.ClassCastException:
>       com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.SalesforceSDKManager cannot be cast to
>       com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager  at
>       com.salesforce.androidsdk.smartstore.app.SmartStoreSDKManager.getInstance(SmartStoreSDKManager.java:132)
>       at
>       com.runtime.activity.home.HomeActivity.setDefualtConfiguration(HomeActivity.java:163)
>       at
>       com.runtime.activity.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:82)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)  at
>       android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
>       at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)  
>       at
>       android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at
>       android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>       android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)   at
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: please format your question and elaborate in precise way.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of document read i found the solutions.

in my app file onCreate method just do this changes.

```
  //SalesforceSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new NativeKeyImpl(), SplashActivity.class);

  Comment the above line of code and put this line of code.

  SmartSyncSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new NativeKeyImpl(), SplashActivity.class);

   This line of code initialise smartstore SDK. The problem is soved
```

Comment: @mobility what does the scond and the third parameter stand for ? I encountered the sames problem here. Thank you

Comment: @Rodrigo The second parameter is taking a key and third one is app launcher activity.

Comment: @mobility what does mean the taking key and how can i get it ? can you please help me. Regards

Comment: @mobility do you mean i need just to put SmartSyncSDKManager.initNative(getApplicationContext(), new NativeKeyImpl(), SplashActivity.class); without istructions above ??

Comment: @Rodrigo you should write this code in your application class and use it like below code.

Comment: class NativeKeyImpl implements KeyInterface {

 @Override
 public String getKey(String name) {
  return Encryptor.hash(name + "12s9adpahk;n12-97sdainkasd=012", name + "12kl0dsakj4-cxh1qewkjasdol8");
 }
}

Comment: @mobility can you provide me please the source code of using smartStore in native android. I am stuck and I need help.

Comment: @mobility I am newbie to Salesforce SDK development and I have encountered many issues on it. Can you  help me please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147163/discussion-between-mobility-and-rodrigo).